# Get file size in Java from relative path to file

Tags: java, liferay, filesize

How can I get file size in Java if I have a relative path to a file such as:

```
String s = "/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc"
```

I tried with two diferent strings:

```
  String[] separatedPath = s.split("/");
  List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(separatedPath);  
  String ret = "/" + wordList.get(1) + "/" + wordList.get(2) + "/" + wordList.get(3)+ "/" + wordList.get(4);    
  s = ret;
```

In this case s="/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf";

In second case s="/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc"

I tried with:

```
File file1 = new File(s);
long filesize = file1.length();
```

and with:

```
String filePath = new File(s).toURI().getPath();
File file2 = new File(filePath);
long filesize2 = file1.length();
```

and also with (if the problem is in not providing full path):

```
String absolutePath = FileUtil.getAbsolutePath(file1);
File file3 = new File(absolutePath);
long filesize3 = file3.length();
byte[] bytes1=FileUtil.getBytes(file1);
byte[] bytes2=FileUtil.getBytes(file2);
byte[] bytes3=FileUtil.getBytes(file3);
```

I am always getting in debug that filesizes in all cases are 0.

Maybe is worth noticing that the three attributes of file1 and file2 and file3 are always:

```
 filePath: which is always null; 
 path: "/documents/19/21704/liferay-portlet-development.pdf"
 prefixLength: 1
```

Since I am also using Liferay I also tried their utility.

```
  long compId = article.getCompanyId();
  long contentLength = DLStoreUtil.getFileSize(compId, CompanyConstants.SYSTEM, s);
```

I also should notice that in my .xhtml view I can access the file with:

```
<a target="_blank" 
href="/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc">
     file2.pdf 
</a>
```

Pdf opens in a new window. So it is stored on my server.

What am I doing wrong here? That I cant get the file size from bean?

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I suppose `/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf` is a file and the rest is a section inside not another file.

Comment: You are running on linux/unix right ?

Comment: So.. what is the path to `/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf` on the server? It's a www path, so you need to work out a server path based on that. With the information you've given, it can be anything, so you need to tell us what is the path on your file system (relative to your executing code, for example).

Comment: Yes I am running on linux. Yes it's a relative path like localhost:8080/documents/...

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use the File.length() method to get the file size in bytes.

```
File file =new File("c:\\java_xml_logo.jpg");

if(file.exists()){

double bytes = file.length();
}
System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your "relative" path is expressed as an absolute path (begining with "/", which is read as FS root).

A relative file path should look like:

- `documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc`
- `./documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc`

Or, you could get your application root folder File and compose the absolute path:

```
File rootFolder =new File("path to your app root folder");

File myfile=new File(rootFolder, "/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc");
```

Comment: Now my "path" in my variables "file1","file2","file3" is /home/roq/Documents/apps/eclipseLiferay/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc. But still the size remains 0.

Comment: Have you checked what the `file.exists()` method return on each case?

Comment: Just did. It doesn't find the file in any case. I tried with three strings "documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc", "/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc" and "./documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d023-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc". It doesnt find the file in any case. Hm.

Comment: So, you should check if the file resides under the application folder (as you posted at the first comment, your app is running under `/home/roq/Documents/apps/eclipseLiferay` folder), or it is being created under other location.

Comment: Probably you are right. It cannot find it under the directory you mentioned. I upload the picture through some cms system ie.: liferay. And probably liferay stores the path to it. And this path I can access from liferay, it returns as mentioned: "/documents/19/21704/file2.pdf/0929c695-d0‌​23-49d7-a8ff-65ccea46bebc". The last part after .pdf probably means some encoded path to the file?? I'll probably try using some other liferay utilities to get the file in my bean.

Comment: Ok. Try with `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.DLStoreUtil`  utility class and some of its convenience methods.

Comment: Are you familiar with liferay? Because for the method DLStoreUtil.getFileSize() I cant seem to get the third attribute file path right. I tried four different paths and always I get no such file exception. If you care to read:

Document document = SAXReaderUtil.read(article.getContentByLocale(myContent));
 nodes = document.selectNodes("/root/dynamic-element[@name='" + fieldname +"']/dynamic-content");
  for (Node node : nodes){                                       String s = node.getText();
separated1 = s.parsed_as_described_above_on_my_stackovrlw_question

Comment: And then I try  DLStoreUtil for following strings; String s; String separated1; String Sub1 = s.substring(1); String substringSepareted1=separated1.substring(1);